# PHP - Codeigniter twitter loops

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, twitter

new here!!

Im trying to get tweets to display on a site(framework is codeigniter). I am using the twitter api (for example: https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/ddarrko.xml) to get the tweets and subsequently insert them into a database which I will then get to display on the site. The actual code runs fine the issue is it only ever processes one tweet. my code is -

//get twitter address

```
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $getadd = $this->admin_model->get_settings("twitter_address");
    $twitter_user = $getadd->item_value;
    //define twitter xml file

    $xmlpath = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/".$twitter_user.".xml";

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlpath);


    foreach ($xml->status as $tweet);
    {
        echo "<pre>";print_r($xml);echo "</pre>";
        $this->data->username=$twitter_user;
        $this->data->twitter_status=$tweet->text;
        $this->data->pub_date=$tweet->created_at;

        //load model and insert tweets;
        $this->load->model('tweet_model');
        $this->tweet_model->insert_tweets($this->data);

    }
```

as you can see I am defining to run each status in xml file. The echo pre line is me testing because when printing $tweet only one tweet is coming up however even if i loop through just $xml still only one tweet is processed despite there being loads in the file.

any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will give you all the available tweets from XML. you can manipulate below logic as per your need.

```
$xmlpath = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/".$twitter_user.".xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlpath);
$count_tweet = sizeof($xml);
for($i=0 ; $i < $count_tweet  ; $i++)
{
        echo"<br>Tweet: ". $xml->status[$i]->text;
        echo"<br>date:".$xml->status[$i]->created_at."<br>";
}
```

Thanks.